# WSO2 Identity Server custom Tenant Listener

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to introduce a custom tenant listener to WSO2 Identity Server in order to hook on tenant creation and apply some common configuration I need for all tenants that will be created on my server (for example some common roles, a common secondary user store, etc).

After some digging, I ended up extending `AbstractIdentityTenantMgtListener` and since I couldn't find any documentation for something like what I'm doing (I've seen the docs for user store listeners but it doesn't seem to be quite the same thing) I ended up creating an OSGI component and adding it to drop-ins but my problem is that while my service is registered, it is not active and doesn't get called any time.

What I have is very minimal at the moment, just to get the hook called. Something like this:

```java
/**
 * @scr.component name="org.wso2is.tenantlistener.internal.TenantListenerServiceComponent" *
 *     immediate="true"
 */
public class TenantListenerServiceComponent {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TenantListenerServiceComponent.class);

    protected void activate(ComponentContext context) {
        log.info("Trying to activate Tenant Listener");
        try {
        BundleContext bundleContext = context.getBundleContext();
            MyTenantListener listener = new MyTenantListener();
            ServiceRegistration<?> serviceRegistration = bundleContext.registerService(
                MyTenantListener.class.getName(), listener, null);
        log.info("Tenant Listener bundle is activated with id: " + serviceRegistration.getReference().getBundle().getBundleId());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.fatal("----Error while activating Tenant listener----", e);
        }
    }

    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext context) {
        log.info("Tenant Listener bundle is de-activated");
    }

}
```

```java
public class MyTenantListener extends AbstractIdentityTenantMgtListener {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyTenantListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onTenantCreate(TenantInfoBean tenantInfoBean) throws StratosException {
        log.info("Hooking on tenant creation!! Received a new tenant: " + tenantInfoBean.getTenantId() + ", " + tenantInfoBean.getTenantDomain());
    }

    @Override
    public int getListenerOrder() {
        return 999;
    }

}
```

Additionally my bundle configuration looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.1</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
      <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
      <Private-Package>org.wso2is.tenantlistener.internal</Private-Package>
      <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework,javax.servlet,
        javax.servlet.http,
        *;resolution:=optional
      </Import-Package>
      <Export-Package>!org.wso2is.tenantlistener.internal,org.wso2is.tenantlistener.*;</Export-Package>
      <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I even tried to add my listener to my `deployment.toml` like follows but got nothing:

```
[[event_handler]]
name= "org.wso2is.tenantlistener.MyTenantListener"
```

Has anyone tried something similar with success (getting a custom tenant listener to actually get called)? It probably is some detail that I'm missing but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after all, after some additional digging in WSO2' repositories and more specifically [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/1469/files) PR helped me identify my problem.

Just for reference to anyone else that might face a similar issue, the problem was how I was registering my service. Instead of using the name of my concrete implementation, I should have used `TenantMgtListener`'s interface.

So the service registration line on `TenantListenerServiceComponent::activate` should have been:

```java
 ServiceRegistration<?> serviceRegistration = bundleContext.registerService(TenantMgtListener.class.getName(), listener, null);
```